# file_get_contents get data after 5 second from loading the web-page

Tags: php, file-get-contents

i want to check if source web-page has certain word or not in PHP , but the web-page load after 5 seconds

tried classic way but didn't worked because it load the page immediately

```
    <?php
   $urlmain = "http://example.com";
    $url = file_get_contents("$urlmain");
    if (strpos($url, 'buy') !== false) {
        $pid= 'Available';

    }elseif (strpos($url, 'sold') !== false) {
        $pid= 'Sold';

    }else{ 
               $pid= 'can't get data';
    }

     echo $pid;

    ?>
```

in previous code i want file_get_contents to get data after 5 second from loading the web-page

$url = file_get_contents("$url");

Any Idea?

Comment: Where is `$url` set? Also your missing a quote so the code won't work, plus hopefully the page has no other instances of buy or sold on the page, you would be better off properly scraping it using a dom parser, like [domdocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: If you need to load page before requesting data, you wouldn't be able to do it in 1 request - your best bet would be to send request via js to a php script that would actually do the file_get_contents

Comment: "After 5 seconds" is unlikely how it works. You'll get the base HTML as is. It's more likely you were observing some delayed AJAX request. See browser devtools / F12 and the network tab.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to load page before requesting data, you wouldn't be able to do it in 1 request.

Your best bet would be to load page normally (without any `file_get_contents`), wait for 5 seconds, send request via JS to a PHP script that would actually do the `file_get_contents`. Note that your code should end with `die();`, otherwise your second request will get whole page on top of your results.

Try following:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

  // This is your code to get data

  $url = file_get_contents("$url");
  if (strpos($url, 'buy') !== false) {
    $pid = 'Available';

  } elseif (strpos($url, 'sold') !== false) {
    $pid = 'Sold';

  } else {
    $pid = 'can\'t get data';
  }

  echo $pid;
  die();
}
?>
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
    // On page load we start counting for 5 seconds, after which we execute function
    window.onload = setTimeout(function (){
        // We prepare AJAX request to the same PHP script, but via POST method
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = '';
        http.open('POST', url, true);

        http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        // When we get back successful results, we will output them to HTML node with ID = output
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200) {
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = http.responseText;
            }
        }
        http.send();
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: Should i change anything in <script> section ?

Comment: @Dr.Mezo Pretty much - you will need to show that data to user, but how to do that it completely depend on the HTML. I'll update answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You should use PHP cURL extension:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```